# docker run with default command in TeamCity command line build step

Tags: docker, teamcity

I want to run a docker container with its default command in a TeamCity build step. I tried using a build step of type "Command line" and then specifying the docker container to run under "Docker settings" -> "Run step within docker container".

Unfortunately, this requires specifying a command. I tried passing just a comment, but of course this is then overriding the default command of the container.

Of course, I could instead just run the full docker command in the build step, but this would require additional installation of docker on the build machine, which I would like to circumvent and use the build in docker abilities of TeamCity.

Does anyone have an idea how to make TeamCity run the default command of the container?

EDIT: I worked around the issue for now by finding out the ENTRYPOINT of the container I want to run, and specifying it as the command to run in the build step. This works for now, but since it adds some unnecessary coupling to the setup of the container it still would be nice to know how to run the default command of the container.

Comment: Ran into the same problem. Did you find any better workaround?